# Entity Framework 6 with multiple providers

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework-6

I have an application which is using Entity Framework 6 in order to interact with a SQL Server database. I have several migrations files due to the evolution of the application.

Now, I'd like to add the possibility to choice between a SQL Server database and a PostgreSQL database with keeping the same entity model.

When I apply the migrations files on SQL Server, all is ok.

But when I apply the same migrations files on PostgreSQL, it says that the database does not match the entity model and I have to generate a new migration file.

If I generate a new migration file, I see that it want to remove the property unicode on all string columns. I think it's because on PostgreSQL the type `varchar` (character varying) is able to store unicode and non unicode characters.

If I apply this migration file on PostgreSQL, all is ok now. But if I apply it on SQL Server, it say that the database does not match the entity model => columns varchar has been replaced per nvarchar.

I thought that the migrations files was able to adapt to the provider but apparently not.

For information, the property unicode is manage like that in the onModelCreating method :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyTable>()
.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
.IsUnicode(false);
```

So, my question is, do I have to manage different migration files depending on provider, knowing that I want to keep the same entity model ? If yes, how can I do this ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I'm not sure it's the best but it's working.
In order not to be annoy anymore, I've created a batch migrations files per provider.
For that I've created one configuration per provider with specifying a specific context key and a different folder containing the migrations files.
This permits to switch between the different configurations depending of the current provider.

Comment: How did you create two configurations? I am facing the same issue. How did you run different migration folder?